# displaying validation error message for blank field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop down list control. I want to display an empty error message if the user does not select any item in  the drop down. below is the HTMl markup for the drop down because the actual drop down is in Telerik:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                        <label style="font-weight:bold" class="control-label required" for="AwardId">Nominated for these Awards</label>
                        <input disabled="disabled" id="AwardName" name="AwardName" required="required" style="width:100%" type="text" value="" /><script>kendo.syncReady(function(){jQuery("#AwardName").kendoDropDownList({"autoBind":false,"cascadeFrom":"EmployeeNumber","dataTextField":"AwardCategory1","dataValueField":"AwardId","enable":false,"optionLabel":"Select award...","dataSource":{"transport":{"read":{"url":"/AdditionalInformation/Cascading_GetAwards","data":filterAwards},"prefix":""},"serverFiltering":true,"filter":[],"schema":{"errors":"Errors"}}});});</script>
                    </div>
```

This is the input button at the bottom of the page.

```
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"  />
```

I tried to display the error message this way:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="checkValidity()" />

<script>
      function checkValidity()
    {
        
        const inpObj = document.getElementById("AwardName");
        alert(inpObj);
        if (!inpObj.checkValidity()) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = inpObj.validationMessage;
    }
</script>
```

when I run my code and click on submit button. I dont see  any error message.

Comment: Your code is all commented out.

Comment: removed all the comments. I did this for testing to check that control is going to the function.

Comment: Would advise you use `submit` action versus `click`. Also you may want to prevent the event perform the validation, and then decide to return true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following.

```html
<form>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label style="font-weight:bold" class="control-label required" for="AwardId">Nominated for these Awards</label>
    <input disabled="disabled" id="AwardName" name="AwardName" required="required" style="width:100%" type="text" value="" />
    <script>
      kendo.syncReady(function() {
        jQuery("#AwardName").kendoDropDownList({
          "autoBind": false,
          "cascadeFrom": "EmployeeNumber",
          "dataTextField": "AwardCategory1",
          "dataValueField": "AwardId",
          "enable": false,
          "optionLabel": "Select award...",
          "dataSource": {
            "transport": {
              "read": {
                "url": "/AdditionalInformation/Cascading_GetAwards",
                "data": filterAwards
              },
              "prefix": ""
            },
            "serverFiltering": true,
            "filter": [],
            "schema": {
              "errors": "Errors"
            }
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="checkValidity()" />
</form>
<script>
  function checkValidity(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const inpObj = document.getElementById("AwardName");
    alert(inpObj);
    if (!inpObj.checkValidity()) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = inpObj.validationMessage;
      return false;
    }
    return true;
</script>
```

This performs the action on `click` event and prevents the default event action. It should check validity and if it is valid, continue (`return true` will continue the event), otherwise show the highlight (`return false` will keep the event stopped).

Since user can `submit` the form without clicking the button, they can bypass this entirely. It is better to perform validity in the Submit action rather than just when the User clicks submit button.